# Error: property "#{$name}" must be followed by a ':'

Tags: sass

Can this even be done? Upon compilation I get this error **Error: property "#{$name}" must be followed by a ':'**

The line it's moaning about is **@include hidden-#{$name};**

```
@mixin generate-visibility {
    @each $name in ($break-list) {
        .hidden--#{$name} {
            @include hidden-#{$name};
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sass doesn't allow to interpolate in name mixins nor functions, so the next:

```
@mixin foo{
  content:'foo';
}

.foo{
  @include #{'foo'};
}
```

returns

```
Invalid CSS after "  @include ": expected identifier, was "#{'foo'};"
```

It is issued [here](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/626)